# How do I find all solutions to $\sin(x+(\pi/7))=-1/\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck on the $\pi/7$ since it doesn't have known exact value-please help!

Comment: What do you mean "known exact value"? Its exact value is $\pi/7$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.  Let $y=x+\pi/7$.  Solving $\sin y=-1/\sqrt2$ is easy because you know the exact values, and then solving for $x$ is easy because you don't need to know any exact values!

Comment: I have solved for y at (5π/4) and (7π/4), how do I go about solving for x?

Comment: What is the relation between $y$ and $x$?

Comment: Not sure of the relation, that is where I'm stuck. Is x= 45π/28 and x=31π/28?

Comment: OK.  Maybe I shouldn't use complicated words like "relation".  Look through my answer and see if you can find an **equation** which has both $x$ and $y$ in it.

Comment: Ok with that said, the answers for x I came up with should be correct- since x=π/7 - y